# How to create URL in laravel with uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

For SEO i need create URL in the form of uppercase or lowercase.

For example (Original URL):

```
https://example.com/CATEGORY/product
```

If user run this URL:

```
https://example.com/category/product or https://example.com/CATEGORY/PRODUCT
```

Converto to:

```
https://example.com/CATEGORY/product
```

How to create this URL in `web.php` ?

Comment: Why would you need that? URLs are essentially case-invariant.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov , Hi, Doublicate URL error for SEO. I need just run this URL: `https://example.com/CATEGORY/product`

Comment: urls are case insensitive. what do u mean by doublicate URL can u share more info.

Comment: Show us your existing routes (including an example of one not working)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work (I'm making assumptions about what you are using category and product params for.

```
Route::get('{category}/{product}', function($category, $product) 
{
    $product = Product::where('product_title', strtolower($product))
        ->and('category', strtolower($category))
        ->get();

    return $product;
});
```

Key points:

- The router doesn't care if its uppercase or lowercase
- You, need to establish how to convert from one case to the other - in the above example, I just converted to lower case (but you may need to use studley case, kebab case, etc (checkout the Laravel helpers part of the docs)).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your specific question correctly, you want to redirect users to 
    https://example.com/CATEGORY/product
if they hit any url that contains the same characters but use different capitalization, such as
    https://example.com/category/product

This kind of redirect could be handled by adding redirect logic to the route in @Chris answer.

```
Route::get('{category}/{product}', function($category, $product) 
{
    if(strtoupper($category) != $category || strtolower($product) != $product) {
        return redirect(strtoupper($category).'/'.strtolower($product));
    }

    $product = Product::where('product_title', strtolower($product))
        ->and('category', strtolower($category))
        ->get();

    return $product;
});
```

Laravel returns a 302 code by default, which indicates a temporary redirect. This is because it is much better to accidentally send a temporary redirect than to accidentally send a permanent one. In this case, it sounds like you might want to make it permanent, so add the return code to your redirect call.

```
return redirect(strtoupper($category).'/'.strtolower($product), 301);
```

That way their browser will remember to always the route you want. It will also indicate to search engines to index the correct url.

Unlike Apache, Nginx urls are case-sensitive. This is to improve performance. Laravel routes are also case-sensitive. So if you are using a Laravel + Nginx stack then you have to consider case in all your routes. You could handle redirects in the Nginx configuration, but in this case matching on http://example.com/*/* could easily catch urls you didn't intend to.